# Conceptual understanding of silk damping

Tags: cosmology, astronomy, scattering, perturbation-theory, cosmic-microwave-background

CMB anisotropies are washed out below the [silk damping scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffusion_damping), because photons travel out of overdense regions. However does silk damping also damp matter perturbations (through scattering) on scales of order of the expected photon travel distance? Or is this effect too tiny to be measured in the matter power spectrum?